# two small bootstrap css styles so the page in Firefox and Chrome looks completely different? Example is inside

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

Here is the code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dZBWh/)

It looks properly in Chrome (radiobuttons are OK although 3 of 6 radiobuttons are left to the left border of browser), but looks completely different in Firefox (the radiobuttons in Firefox are messed).

How to fix the problem with css styles? **The styles are taken from twitter bootstrap so they could be overrided only.**

Also, html can't be touched if possible, only css.
Is that a crossbrowser bug? What's the reason it looks completely different?

The full code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


        <style>

            label
            {
                display       : block;
                margin-bottom : 5px
            }

            .radio input[type="radio"], .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]
            {
                float       : left;
                margin-left : -18px
            }

        </style>


    </head>
    <body>


        <div style="border:1px solid red; ">
            <label class="radio">
                <input name="count" value="A" type="radio">
                A </label>
            <label class="radio">
                <input name="count" value="B" type="radio">
                B </label>
            <label class="radio" style="border:1px solid blue;">
                <input name="count" value="C" type="radio">
                C </label>
        </div>

        <div style="margin-left: 300px; margin-top: -70px;">
            <label class="radio">
                <input name="count2" value="D" type="radio">
                D </label>
            <label class="radio">
                <input name="count2" value="E" type="radio">
                E </label>
            <label class="radio">
                <input name="count2" value="F" type="radio">
                F </label>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your float.

Remove the float left from

```
.radio input[type="radio"], .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]
```

Comment: Thank you, but as I noted above I can't modify twitter bootstrap. I can only overwrite their style.

Comment: you can overwrite in your default css

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, float and margin-left are being set by bootstrap to values that you don't want.

In order to override them all you need to do is add styles to your page (or preferably a bootstrap override css file, i.e. one added after you have added bootstrap) that will override the bootstrap values you don't want e.g.

```
.radio input[type="radio"], .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]
            {
                float       : none;
                margin-left : 0px
            }​
```